# Login form not work

Tags: symfony

I try to create a connection system with form.
But I still get the message: "Bad credentials."

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Tp\Bundle\AppBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        tp:
            entity: { class: TpAppBundle:User, property: email }
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
             pattern:  ^/login$
             security: false
        tp:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: tp
            #anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: user_index
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: login


<?php
namespace Tp\Bundle\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }
        return $this->render('TpAppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'email' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}

class User implements UserInterface {
...
```

In my date base, 
User
email:test@test.com
password: test

But unable to connect.
I still have the same message: Bad credentials.

Have you any idea?
Do you need more?

Thank you very much

Comment: could you show us the login form ?

Comment: Of course: 
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}{{ parent() }} - Connexion{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="_username" value="{{ email }}" />

        <label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}

Comment: every thing seems to be ok. check your log , you will have a clearer error message, if you happen to get it paste it here as well we may could help you.